# Break figure description over two pages

Tags: floats, captions

I use figures with a caption and a description below. Sometimes the figures are large and also the descriptions. If I keep the images to a not very low scale (to make them understable) the descriptions, even in a very small font, exceed the page height.

I would like to find a way to break these descriptions over two pages in an "automatic" way since I have many figures and if I do it manually is a mess.

I have been googling and looking for in several fora and no solution yet. Could someone give me a hand on this? I provide the following MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
{\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{latex_logo.png} \label{figurelabel}
}
\caption{This is my figure caption}
\medskip
\small
This is the figure description
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're running up against is that LaTeX, by design, requires a "float" (such as a `figure` or `table` environment) to occupy no more than a single page. Page breaks within one and the same float are, by design, neither permitted nor enabled.

Rather than augment and/or rewrite substantial portions of the LaTeX kernel, you may decide to use the [caption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package and its "ContinuedFloat" mechanism. It won't let you create floats larger than one page, let alone provide automatic page breaking within a "float". However, it does provide a reasonably good way of dealing with figures and tables whose material simply won't fit on a single page. An example is given below.

You weren't very specific about how large the extended floats are. In the example below, I assume that the figure and its extended description take up about 1-1/4 pages in total; I've broken this up into two parts that each span slightly more than half a page. Obviously, your layout preferences and needs should dictate the final layout of these extended floats.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum,kantlipsum} % for filler text
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\section{The beginning}
\kant[1-2]
\begin{figure}[t!]
\caption{Figure caption}\label{figurelabel}
{\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{latex_logo.png} 
\par
}
\bigskip
\small
This is the figure description.
\lipsum[1-3]
\flushright \emph{(continued)}
\hrule % consider using a visual separator between float material and running text
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{Figure caption, continued}
\small % use same font style as in first part of figure.
\lipsum[4-8]

\smallskip
\hrule % consider using a visual separator between float material and running text
\end{figure}
\kant[3-6]
\end{document}
```