# Break box (a long caption) over pages

Tags: floats, captions, page-breaking, boxes, width

I want to have text of a certain width less than the page width, which goes across several pages. Normally you’d put text into a (`\par`)`box` to set its width but these boxes cannot be broken across pages so I can’t use it here.

I tried looking at the internal definition of `\parbox` (more precisely `\@iiiparbox`) but I cannot make heads nor tails of it – it doesn’t look like it can be adapted to allow page breaks, though.

#### Background:

The reason I want to do this is that I have a figure caption (which is centered and of a given text width) and is too long for the page and thus cut off. There are numerous questions about how to solve this (e.g. [Break figure description over two pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112293/42)) but none offers an actual solution to the problem.

For now I’ve simply opted out of using a `float` and use the following instead:

```
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics
    \captionof{figure}{looooong caption}
\end{center}
```

… but that always puts the figure caption on the next page in its entirety, rather than breaking it. (Locally) redefining `\@iiiparbox` makes it possible to break the figure caption across pages smoothly but then the figure caption takes up the complete page width which is undesired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default definition of `\caption` in `article` and the other standard classes is not boxed if the caption is more than a line.  To change the effective line width you should use `quote` (or an environment with similar definition) which is

```
\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

Which just accepts the default increase of `\leftmargin` and makes `\rightmargin` the same. You can set the two margins explicitly to any appropriate value in the definition of a custom environment to wrap the caption

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics

\nopagebreak
\begin{quote}
\captionof{figure}{looooong caption}
\end{quote}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Oh, I was unaware of that. The document uses the `caption` package with some options, which redefines `\caption` to be inside a `parbox`. Thanks, I’ll try this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If the actual version of the `caption` package is used, the `\parbox` can be switched off by option `parbox=none`. But be aware that from now on not all features of the `caption` package are working as expected anymore, for example the `indention` parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn’t work – it may be due to the fact that I’m using a double-sided layout. If I change `\oddsidemargin` and `\evensidemargin` then I get an effect but that effect isn’t restricted to the figure caption, it also indents the figure itself (and even the whole page before that). Furthermore, I don’t succeed in applying  an actual margin and making the text less wide – instead, it just *shifts* the whole page to the right by increasing the outer margin (even though I explicitly decreased the `\textwidth` as well).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not sure what you meant didn't work, but changing `\oddsidemargin` or `\evensidemargin` or especially `\textwidth` is almost certainly going to make things go wrong. Changing those within a document is just not really supported. The way to change the margins locally is to use a list environment like `quote` as I showed.

Comment: @David Yes, I realised that in the meantime. Regarding your `quote` code: from everything I read this should work – alas, it doesn’t. It also doesn’t work when I use them `enumitem` package and change the margins via the option `leftmargin=3cm`. I’m suspecting that the (rather complex and badly written) custom document class interferes in nontrivial ways.

Comment: Okay, this solution works – just not with the `caption` package, even when passing `parbox=none`. No idea why … I ended up hacking together a substitute `xcaptionof` command to take the place of the regular `captionof`.